# Mousedown/move/up not working in sync

Tags: jquery, mousedown, mouseup

Seems like a weird problem but probably a simple answer.

Check out this **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gcnuf)**.

You'll see that I've set it up where on `mousedown`, it checks for selected text. If true and not empty, it sets `text_selected` to 1 (or true) and returns the selected text.

On `mouseup`, *if* `text_selected` is true, it should print 1 and the selected text... but it doesn't!

If you click it a 2nd time it will, but that's no good. Why isn't it updating prior to `mouseup`?

Comment: This does not look right `$(window).on('mousemove',checkForSelectedText());` try without the ()

Comment: @mplungjan I swear that gets me every time. Works like a charm now - thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that binding on mouse up is sufficient: `$(window).on('mouseup', function(e) { showSelectedText()});` the function `showSelectedText` is only a wrapper around your code: `$('.ph').text('Text selected: '+checkForSelectedText());`

Comment: True. It does encompass all I'm desiring to do with one event.